# Project compiles on Ubuntu but not on Debian

Tags: c++, gcc, boost, c++20

I have a strange problem where one of my projects is compiling just fine on Ubuntu 22.04 and Windows but gives a strange linker error on Debian bullseye even with the same gcc and cmake versions.

On Debian I get this linker error here:

```
#16 953.5 `_ZN5boost4asio12async_resultINS0_15use_awaitable_tINS0_15any_io_executorEEEJFvNS_6system10error_codeEmEEE8initiateEPZNS8_8initiateINS0_6detail36initiate_async_write_buffer_sequenceINS0_19basic_stream_socketINS0_2ip3tcpES3_EEEEJSt5arrayINS0_12const_bufferELm4EENSA_14transfer_all_tEEEENS0_9awaitableImS3_EET_S4_DpT0_E305_ZN5boost4asio12async_resultINS0_15use_awaitable_tINS0_15any_io_executorEEEJFvNS_6system10error_codeEmEEE8initiateINS0_6detail36initiate_async_write_buffer_sequenceINS0_19basic_stream_socketINS0_2ip3tcpES3_EEEEJSt5arrayINS0_12const_bufferELm4EENSA_14transfer_all_tEEEENS0_9awaitableImS3_EET_S4_DpT0_.Frame.destroy' referenced in section `.rodata.cst8' of src/gw2cc/Release/libgw2cc_lib.a(SecureTokenServerClient.cpp.o): defined in discarded section `.text._ZN5boost4asio12async_resultINS0_15use_awaitable_tINS0_15any_io_executorEEEJFvNS_6system10error_codeEmEEE8initiateEPZNS8_8initiateINS0_6detail36initiate_async_write_buffer_sequenceINS0_19basic_stream_socketINS0_2ip3tcpES3_EEEEJSt5arrayINS0_12const_bufferELm4EENSA_14transfer_all_tEEEENS0_9awaitableImS3_EET_S4_DpT0_E305_ZN5boost4asio12async_resultINS0_15use_awaitable_tINS0_15any_io_executorEEEJFvNS_6system10error_codeEmEEE8initiateINS0_6detail36initiate_async_write_buffer_sequenceINS0_19basic_stream_socketINS0_2ip3tcpES3_EEEEJSt5arrayINS0_12const_bufferELm4EENSA_14transfer_all_tEEEENS0_9awaitableImS3_EET_S4_DpT0_.Frame.destroy[_ZN7network6socks56socketIN5boost4asio19basic_stream_socketINS3_2ip3tcpENS3_15any_io_executorEEEE10do_connectERKNS5_14basic_endpointIS6_EERKNSt7__cxx1112basic_stringIcSt11char_traitsIcESaIcEEESL_]' of src/gw2cc/Release/libgw2cc_lib.a(SecureTokenServerClient.cpp.o)
```

The project is using vcpkg to download and build all dependencies. Would be great if somebody could tell me what is causing this. All Linux compilations were done in a clean docker image with just the necessary dependencies installed. I even tried different gcc versions on Debian without any success.

Comment: Same boost version?

Comment: yes the boost version is fixed via vcpkg (all dependencies are)